# How to activate EE as plattform for an extension on magentocommerce.com?

Tags: extensions, magento-enterprise, magento-connect

We've a lot of extensions developed, which are available on magentocommerce.com, but only activated for the CE plattform, but most of them work also perfectly in EE.

In the administration panel for the extension it's only possible to activate different CE versions, but non EE versions, even if we have a silver partner account associated. We already tried to contact some guys at Magento and eBay, but didn't get any reply of how to activate a extension also for EE.

Does anyone have experience with acitvating an extension also for the EE plattform on magentocommerce.com? What did you have to do? Who can we contact?

Just to be clear: This question is not about what to change in our code, it's how can we activate EE versions in our magentocommerce.com account, to provide some of our extensions also for EE.

Comment: It depends on account type. Contact magentocommerce.com support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a right reserved for industry partners only

> Magento Industry Partners have the ability to sell both an Enterprise and Community compatible version of their extension on our application marketplace, Magento Connect

See http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/IndustryPartnerOneSheet.pdf

Comment: And do we have to activate that somehow, because even our Silver Partner account (where we can also download the EE itself) is not allowed to add EE version extensions.

Comment: You work for Sitewards - who is a Solution Partner - not an Industry Partner. They are two different programs. Magento might still let you list EE products, but the industry program is geared towards those that mass re-sell extensions; and the solution program for those that build bespoke stores (not re-sell extensions).

Comment: If you do get an answer from your "Partner Manager" - be sure to post a reply in the comments here.

Comment: We waited for that already since January, so don't expect anything right now :)

Comment: We have an EE only extension we're launching.  I'm going to try marketing outside of connect for starters.  If you have compelling EE functionality in your extension talk to some Magento sales reps you work with and get them excited about it so they suggest it to new EE leads.

Comment: @TobiasZander - beats our reply to our Platinum Hosting Partnership. We've been waiting since September '12 on that ...